# How can I print a Crystal Report when a button is clicked?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

How can I print a report when a button is clicked?

How can I make a total of a single column data in Crystal Reports?

Can anyone give me some sort of hint?

Comment: Hint for totaling - try to right-click on data field in CR design window ;)

Answer (score 2):

How to Print a Crystal Report Programmatically

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CRPrinting10062006161454PM/CRPrinting.aspx

Printing Crystal Reports from VB.Net

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/2d2232d0-af39-438b-930a-ce758dc98ed3

Choosing a printer when printing from Crystal Reports in C#.try to do it VB.Net

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/printtoprinter.aspx